# Excel- using letter codes to replace a number

Tags: excel, reference

Im trying to use the SUM function to add up a combination of values however i need these values to be represented as letters.

Example

_   A
1 dh
2 ak
3 fg

i have the values i want dh, ak, and fg in another column i want the sum to go through column a and whenever it comes to the letters it replaces them with the number in the corresponding values.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This should be migrated to superuser.com as it is an application question and not a programming question.

Comment: My apologies im used to looking things up on here for uni, seemed the place to come when i got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding what you're after but I would be using the `VLookup` function in a separate column then run the sum over the calculated column.

I assume that there is another set of values that the numbers/letters refer to, that these calculations will be based on?

Comment: Yeah i have tried defining names for each of the corresponding keys so all of the values they stand for are named, but the sum function isn't reading them.